# What will be best pattern to merge two Timewindows

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a TimeWindowed KTable

```
stream.table("topicA")
      .groupByKey()
      .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1L))
      .until(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1L)))
      .reduce((value1, value2) -> value2,
              Materialized.as("A-Store"))
```

now I place 4 events in TopicA,

```
key1 Event1 currentTime -90 min
key2 Event2 currentTime -45 min
key1 Event3 currentTime -30 min
key3 Event4 currentTime -15 min
```

not if I fetch events from KTable with the following command

```
fetchAll(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(2),
         System.currentTimeMillis())
```

as expected I receive 4 events from store, including two key1 events delivered different time windows...

Now KTable normal operating mode being always deliver the latest event for the key, how should I deal with this scenario? Sure I can create a Map and insert events there then recollect but that seems clumsy.

Is there a better patter to deal with this, to collect data from 2 different time window and merge them?

Comment: It's unclear to me, what you try to achieve or what your question is.

Comment: Normally my application only deals with last hour, so it get the information from last window and everything will be fine. But lets say I have a production problem and the application was down for 3 hours, so when I restart the application and fetchAll, above scenario will deliver 2 TimeWindows containing same key. Normal operation of the application (1hour intervals) when I query the KTable I get a key only once but this scenario I get twice. Only possible solution seems to me, to iterate over both Timewindows, build new map based on key, process that so question is "a better way to do this?"